# convert animation input shape (beams steel) to square frame shape output

Tags: anylogic

I am importing steel beams to the station and expecting a square shape frame to be out. The current process does work showing the steel beams entering the station. However I can’t see the desired shape (square frame) exiting the station.

Considering the logic statistic, it shows 4 element enter the station and one element out. The logic statistic is correct.

Main question, why I can’t view the square shape agent? Taking in mind the main agent (steel) does appear on the animation conveyer.

[image]

Comment: maybe because you have a sink that actually destroys the batch instantaneously after its creation?

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I have added conveyor Entry, conveyor  and queue before sink. it worked and I have managed to get the required output shape.